# Confusion with finding the range on complex number functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, complex-numbers

The question is about finding the range and domain of $f(z)=e^z$, and I have read the solution and the reason why many times but I just don't understand it. My professor simply taught domain and range with real numbers and gave us complex number question which I don't exactly know how to do, so here's the answer:

> The complex exponential function has natural domain $\mathbb{C}$; hence $f$ has natural domain $\mathbb{C}$. If $z=x+iy$ with $x, y∈\mathbb{R}$ then $e^z=e^x e^{iy} = e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)$. Since $e^x$ can take any positive value, and $y$ can take any value in $\mathbb{R}$ including all those in $(−π, π]$ then $f(z)$ can take any non zero modulus and all arguments. Hence $f(z)$ has the range $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

I think I have a clear understanding on most of it other than the reason why the range would be $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Could you also please tell me a way to find the range for all complex functions too? That would make my life so much easier!

Comment: For *all* ? That's quite a lot...The way or adguing above is nice, and every singl;e case must be dealt with separatedly.

Comment: Did you mean $f(z)=e^z$?  To see that this has a range of $\mathbb C-\{0\}$, just use polar coordinates (as described).  And you can't be serious about "a way to find the range for all complex functions"...there are an awful lot of functions.

Answer (score 1):

$e^x > 0$, view it as the non-zero radius.

$e^{iy}$ is a point on the unit circle, it decides the direction.

Given any non-zero point, find the radius $r$ and the angle $\theta$, we can solve $e^x=r$ and let $y$ be $\theta$.

There is no solution for $e^xe^{iy}=0$, since $e^x$ and $e^{iy}$ are non-zero, we can divide them by their multiplicative inverses and get a contradiction of $1=0$.